# output html on post or page from custom plugin

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development

Is there a way to create a plugin that output custom html on a page or post? I can use the shortcode, but if there is another way please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

To create shortcode write code in the your theme file functions.php

```
 function my_shortcode_fun() {
        $output = $class = '';
        ob_start(); 
            enter code here....
        $output = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        return $output;
    }
    add_shortcode('my-shortcode', 'my_shortcode_fun');
```

Comment: I know how to do it but the problem is with the content of the steps and the numbers of them, I can't rely on the shortcode because I can't know how many steps an user wants to use and what he want to put inside them. I'm creating a wizard plugin

Comment: You can use arguments with function 
function my_shortcode($atts, $content = null) {
$html = '';    
$atts = shortcode_atts(array(
   'id' => null
  ), $atts);

and use the shortcode args by $atts['id'] in code.

Comment: yes, but the the problem remains the content for each step, the attributes of the shortcode will not fit these needings